# Do all null geodesics on a marginally trapped surface remain on or inside the surface?

Tags: general-relativity, event-horizon, causality, geodesics

The definition I've seen and used is essentially "if every congruence orthogonal to a spacelike two-surface has negative expansion, then that surface is said to be trapped." Does this generalize to all null vectors within or on the surface remaining within the volume bounded by the surface?

Comment: What do you mean by remaining within?

Comment: Remaining on would probably have been a better way of stating it. Basically I'd like to be directed to a proof that null geodesics within an apparent horizon remain within the area bounded by the apparent horizon. The definition in terms of families of orthogonal null vectors converging does not obviously generalize to even families of non orthogonal null vectors.

Comment: I'm writing a visualiser for the development and tracking of apparent horizons in numerical relativity, and I had a cool idea for how to do it, but it depends on null geodesics of arbitrary orientation remaining on or inside the apparent horizon. So I guess I have to dig out Wald 

Comment: Are you asking about the horizon or the trapped surface? The trapped surface is a two dimensional surface in a three dimensional spacelike hypersurface, the null geodesics cannot be in, on or out of it.

Comment: The trapped surface(s) is(are) guaranteed to remain inside the event horizon. The trapped surfaces themselves form 3D hypersurfaces in time. Anyway, the families of trapped surfaces divide spacetime into regions within the bounding surfaces and regions outside of them. In that sense, you can ask if all null geodesics inside the volume bounded by the trapped surfaces remain within the volume bounded by the trapped hypersurfaces.

Comment: Then you need to give that definition or explain how a trapped surface, which the way you defined it is a spacelike 2 surface, can be viewed as a 3d surface. Your question is very vague. May be expanded a bit.